# Understanding Eureka <--> Configservice cycle

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to find out what's the best way to solve this conundrum.

1. I'd like Eureka to be able to pick configuration dynamically from the Config Server (Eureka depending on Config)
2. Id' like Config to be found through Eureka, to avoid hardcoding Config's URI in every single microservice (Config depends on Eureka)

`spring:
   cloud:
     enabled: true
   config:
     fail-fast: true
     discovery:
       enabled: true
       serviceId: configserver`

When I startup Eureka, she doesn't know where Config is, so she cannot pick anything from it. What's the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess you would need to launch the config server first. Then tell Eureka where the config server is (using a fixed url), so it can find the configuration to start up. As the config server keeps sending heartbeats, it will be registered in Eureka as soon as it's up. Anyway, I wouldn't go that way. I think you can boot eureka first of all passing some arguments (it's not such a large configuration, after all). Then, launch the rest of your services, including the config server.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking, Eureka's config is not likely to change. Just wanted to check if there was a common best practices about this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your Eureka bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:   
  application:
    name: your_config_file_name   
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      failFast: true
      uri: the_uri_of_the_config_server
```